# link disappears on hover on menubar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have a menu bar like which contains some dropdown icons. some of them have sub menus under icon and some of them have sub-sub menus.

for e.g. Here is a sample for sub-sub-menu

```
 Archives
  |
  |____ 2017
  |      |_______ Award
  |      |_______ Pictures
  |
  |____ 2016
```

When I click on Archive menu then I can see 2017 and 2016 in sub menu under dropdown navigation.

When I hover over Award and Pictures , but when I hover on Award or Pictures then sub-sub menu disappears. for e.g. if I will hover over Award then Award just disappers or I can say font color becomes white because my background is white , when I changed background to other color then I can see the icons. so Its changing the color to white, how can I stop this . here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropdown-menu a.test').on("hover", function(e) {
    $("div.li2017Sub").show();
  });
});
```

```css
.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -1px;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="liPastEvents" class="dropdown" runat="server">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Past Events<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li id="li2017"><a class="test" href="#">2017</a></li>
    <ul>
      <div class="li2017Sub" style="display: none ;">
        <li><a href="http:\\google.com">Pictures</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Award Winners</a></li>
      </div>
    </ul>
    <li id="li2016" runat="server"><a href="/apps/abstractBook/abstractBook2017.aspx">2016</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: create a class with some css properties like: 
    .inner-sub-menu:hover {
        color: balck;
    }
 and attach this "inner-sub-menu" class to your sub sub menu. i.e. Award, Pictures

Comment: it is not working

Answer (score 0):

create css class like:

```
.abc:hover { color: red; }
```

then add this class to `<a>` tag in `<li>` element like:

```
<li><a class="abc" href="http:\\google.com">Pictures</a></li>
<li><a class="abc" href="#">Award Winners</a></li>
```

Comment: not working, I found this line in my css   .navbar-nav li a:hover {
    color: #fff !important;
    }

I think because of this issue is there but when I remove !important then my other menus does not appear to be white on hover

Comment: did you try putting `!important` with `.abc:hover`. i mean `.abc:hover { color: red !important; }`